# how to pass a javascript variable to laravel route?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

**Script code:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function getValue(){
    var getvalue=document.getElementById('brand').value;
    window.location='products' +getvalue;
  }
</script>
```

This is my script code. Here I am trying to pass the value of the variable 'getvalue'to the route.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('products/{getvalue}','categoryController@bValue');
```

This is my route. Here I am trying to pass the getvalue to the controller.

**Controller code:**

```
  public function bValue(Request $getvalue)
{

    echo $getvalue;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work that way, when the route is called 'products/food' food would be your getValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may it will work..

```
 // Javascript
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getValue(){
        var getvalue=document.getElementById('brand').value;
        window.location='products/' +getvalue;
      }
    </script>

// Php
    public function bValue($getvalue)
    {
        echo $getvalue;
    }
```

Comment: How to give the route

Comment: same which is you mentioned in question. You getting any error..?

Comment: See updated answer.....you can refer this. You will have a idea.. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#defining-controllers